# Altering objects that have been set equal

Tags: java, arrays, object, set, equals

I'm setting an array equal to another array.

So let's say array B = array C.

Then, if I do operations on array B, changing it's values, does C also change?

I want to say absolutely not, but I'm having a brain fart and I feel like that what's happening in my code right now.

Comment: What programming language do you use ?

Comment: Yes, the array C would change as well. When you do assignment from one array to another, what's happening is that the variable (`B` in your example) simply refers to the same array that `C` referred to. It doesn't make a duplicate of the array, it just copies the reference.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how to make it so B becomes only a copy of C, and that I can modify B without any changes happening to C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are changed.

The array is an object, so you assign only the reference, after assignment "array B = array C." both variables would hold the same reference. As a result you will have one object and two references

**UPDATE**

For "real copy" you need to use `System.arraycopy()` or `Arrays.copyOf()`

```
int[] arrayC = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] arrayB = new int[arrayC.length];
System.arraycopy(arrayC, 0, arrayB, 0, arrayC.length );
```

Comment: Wow thanks, both of you guys,  that solves that. 

So what would be the best way to make B a copy of array C, so that I can start with C's values, alter them, and not have them actually change array C.

Comment: look on py update - you need to use System.arraycopy() or Arrays.copyOf(). Arrays.copyOf() use System.arraycopy() inside as well. and System.arraycopy() do the copying through JNI - so it must be faster then when you will copy array one by one in the cycle

Answer (score 2):

When you assign one array to another array the array will hold the reference so if you change the value in one array then it will surely change the value of other.

like in your example array B = array C. B will hold the reference to array C. so any changes in array B will reflect in array C.